# File Specific Responses on Swift HTTP Server

Tags: swift, http, server

I am trying to create server software (like HTTPD or NGINX) in Swift. I am using this code:

```
import Darwin.C
let zero = Int8(0)
let transportLayerType = SOCK_STREAM // TCP
let internetLayerProtocol = AF_INET // IPv4
let sock = socket(internetLayerProtocol, Int32(transportLayerType), 0)
let portNumber = UInt16(4000)
let socklen = UInt8(socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size))
var serveraddr = sockaddr_in()
serveraddr.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
serveraddr.sin_port = in_port_t((portNumber << 8) + (portNumber >> 8))
serveraddr.sin_addr = in_addr(s_addr: in_addr_t(0))
serveraddr.sin_zero = (zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, zero)
withUnsafePointer(to: &serveraddr) { sockaddrInPtr in
  let sockaddrPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(sockaddrInPtr).assumingMemoryBound(to: sockaddr.self)
  bind(sock, sockaddrPtr, socklen_t(socklen))
}
listen(sock, 5)
print("Server listening on port \(portNumber)")
repeat {
  let client = accept(sock, nil, nil)
  let html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style='text-align:center;'><h1>Hello from <a href='https://swift.org'>Swift</a> Web Server.</h1></body></html>"
  let httpResponse: String = """
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    server: simple-swift-server
    content-length: \(html.count)

    \(html)
    """
  httpResponse.withCString { bytes in
    send(client, bytes, Int(strlen(bytes)), 0)
    close(client)
  }
} while sock > -1
```

Is there any way to adapt this so that if someone requests a certain file, they would get a certain response instead of just this one page in HTML.

I do not know of any way to do this, having looked through many pieces of code, and been unable to find any solutions.